# Does the sensation of pain arise in the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, neurology, pain

I can feel pain in my arm or in my brain.

I have read that you can feel a phantom pain. As if the pain exists outside the body. There is a related process in the brain but the feeling itself seems to originate at a body spot (or brain spot if the pain is in the brain).

Does pain sensation arise in the spot where I feel the pain or in my brain? If it originates in the brain then how can I feel it in my body? (The same can be asked of sound and vision)

Comment: What have you read on the subject?

Comment: @ChridRogers That you can still feel a phantom pain. As if the pain exists outside the body. There is a related process in the brain but the feeling itself seems to originate at a body spot (or brain spot if the pain is in the brain).